# Is there Monte Carlo localization tool in MATLAB for Simulink model?

Tags: matlab, localization, simulink, robot

Below image shows an example of what I want to do. Using Simulink sl_quadrotor model in an environment with a polygon, lets call it tower, I want the quadrotor to fly up along the tower and from its top to the other side of the tower and then down. I added some arrows on top of the image to clarify the desired path.

In my actual environment I will have many towers.

I need to use Monte Carlo localization.

Is there any already available tool in Simulink/MATLAB for that?

[image]

Update-1:

This is the sl_quadrotor model, I am only changing the x,y,z to be read from the work space.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There aren't any pre-built particle filter (i.e. Monte-Carlo localization) algorithms , but assuming that you're somewhat familiar with the equations that you need to implement, then that can be done using a reasonably simple modification to the standard Kalman Filter algorithm, and there are plenty of examples of them in Simulink.  For instance [Kalman Filter Design](http://www.mathworks.com/help/control/examples/kalman-filter-design.html) or [A simple Kalman Filter in Simulink](http://www.goddardconsulting.ca/simulink-kalman-filter.html).

Comment: Will I have to class the localization method inside the quadrotor model dynamics code? "http://matlab-toolboxes-robotics-vision.googlecode.com/svn-history/r1407/matlab/robot/trunk/simulink/quadrotor_dynamics.m

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "class the .. method", but in general, it'll be difficult for anyone to tell you where to put the code without seeing the model.

Comment: Sorry I meant to say "call"

Comment: I have added an image of the sl_quadrotor model